# Bounty ends are too “in”

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, profile-page

The cosmetic bug report of the day is:

[image: ends in in 1 hour]
[image: ends in tomorrow]
[image: ends in in 3 days]

(On the [bounties tab of user profiles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles?tab=bounties), when there's an active bounty.)

<sub>Could have been worse, at least in doesn't end in 1 hours or in 3 day.</sub>

Comment: No worries, Jeff would come around and smash your head in with a giant 'in' regardlessly.

Comment: [The bug who says In](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_who_say_Ni)

Comment: Those circles don't look freehand to me...

Comment: @Cody My ninth meta post where I include a picture with a pointedly non-hand-drawn circle, and finally someone comments on it (:

Comment: So you're publicly admitting to being a repeat offender? :-)

Comment: @CodyGray Hey, the evidence was out there already. I'm a non-conformist: all my circles are carefully machine-drawn. (The next step would be to always use a ruler.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oops? This will be fixed in the next build.