# "All flagged messages for for kiamlaluno"

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, moderator-tools, flags

If you look at https://chat.stackexchange.com/admin/user-flags/6266, for example, you will notice that the page says, "All flagged messages for **for** kiamlaluno."

[image: screenshot]

The page title is correct: All flagged messages for kiamlaluno.

Comment: If you changed your user name to `for kiamlaluno`, then we'd *really* have a bug on our hands!

Comment: I had to read this twice to see the bug. Isn't Paris lovely this time of year?

Comment: @TheEstablishment Uh-oh! My plan has been discovered.

Comment: Isn't it generally considered rude to point at stuttering?

Comment: [Another](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97243/bounty-ends-are-too-in) preposition gets the spotlight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been already fixed. Now the message says, "All messages by kiamlaluno that have been flagged." The page title is the same as before.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Ah yes, this was already fixed in the code when you posted this question. Thanks for the follow-up, we missed replying here.