# Cannot vote to close as duplicate sometimes

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I'm voting to <s>close</s> mark ["Premium SSL" vs "Stanard SSL" certificates - Any reason why I would want a "Premium SSL"?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29970/premium-ssl-vs-stanard-ssl-certificates-any-reason-why-i-would-want-a-pre) as a duplicate. It already has 4 votes to close as a duplicate of [What are the advantages of EV Certificate?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15865/what-are-the-advantages-of-ev-certificate).

[image: vote to close]

But when I click “duplicate”, the window does not show the URL and preview of that proposed duplicate.

[image: no duplicate]

And if I copy-paste the URL of the duplicate, nothing happens. The “vote to close” button is not enabled.

[image: cannot vote to close]

The behavior is the same whether voting from the question page or from the close review queue. The same happens on SO.

This is happening in Chrome 24.0.1312.57 (the latest version freshly auto-updated) on Windows. Firefox works as expected.

Later, Chrome started working for me. However:

- Others are reporting failures in Chrome as well as in other browsers (Safari, Firefox).
- I still get the same behavior (now on Chrome 24.0.1312.57 on Linux) with *some* questions, but not all. For example, just now, trying to cast the first duplicate vote on [can we show badge number on android app icon like iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937700/can-we-show-badge-number-on-android-app-icon-like-iphone) → [Is there a way to add a badge to an application icon in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905542/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-badge-to-an-application-icon-in-android) :

  [image: SO duplicate prompt timing out]

  From the JavaScript console:

  ```
  setting timeout
  timeout triggered
  Uncaught There are too many kids in the house         full.js:157
    k                                                   full.js:157
    (anonymous function)                                full.js:158
    n                                               jquery.min.js:2
    o.fireWith                                      jquery.min.js:2
    w                                               jquery.min.js:4
    d                                               jquery.min.js:4
  ```

Comment: Looks like a failure of loading an AJAX response. I don't see this (Chrome 24 on Mac) at the moment; did you try a cache clear or force-reload? (the web equivalent of switching it off and on again.. :-P).

Comment: It works for me -- can you try a hard hard hard refresh? This is very new JavaScript.

Comment: @balpha I restarted the browser and shift-reloaded.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either. Chrome crashed in between as well, so this was a hard hard hard refresh.

Comment: Hmm, works for me (on a different question) in the newest Crhome on Windows 7

Comment: I'm currently on version "24.0.1312.56 m" of Chrome and it works for me. In finding the version I was on I triggered an update so I'll see if it still works when that's complete.

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: @balpha Another interesting side-effect [here](http://superuser.com/questions/544990/) is that when I search for "crop" in the duplicate box, it only gives me one result, which *can not* be true, especially given the title of the dupe: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ARCSg.png — I get an `Uncaught There are too many kids in the house` at `full.js:156`.

Comment: @slhck Well, at least Jarrod wins a price for creative error message :)

Comment: @balpha After a reload *now* it's working. Fixed in 2013.2.1.1278. Thanks.

Comment: This question shows a blatant lack of freehand circles.

Comment: @balpha Well, not quite. If I try to cast the first close vote as duplicate for http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165829/javascript-error-when-trying-to-close-a-question-via-the-moderator-queue, I see the message “This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer” and the close button is not enabled. Is this related, or by design? (If it's bad design, why???)

Comment: @XaviLópez http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97243/bounty-ends-are-too-in#comment244744_97243

Comment: Lack of freehand circles - YOU HAVE NO SOUL

Comment: It's currently not working for me, Chrome `24.0.1312.56 m`, and SO `2013.2.1.1280`.

Comment: @balpha So this has affected at least 3 people, but only for a short time. Could it be some client-side cache that you aren't refreshing properly? Or some JS or other resource served with a longer TTL than some other part of the system assumes? Or do you think it's a Chrome bug?

Comment: @slhck The search issue should be fixed after a search re-indexing that's currently running; it uses a new feature.

Comment: Don't you use cache-busting for client-side scripts when they change?

Comment: I get it too, but it seems to come and go.

Comment: I am seeing the same with FireFox 18.0.1

Comment: @balpha This has been happening all day, but only intermittently. Some questions can be marked as duplicate, some can't, and then trying a question a few hours later works. As of right now it still remains an issue. The latest is when trying to close [this](http://serverfault.com/q/474491/126632) question as a duplicate of [this](http://serverfault.com/q/31709/126632) one, resulting in [a hang](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OdzHe.png) and the `Uncaught There are too many kids in the house` error.

Comment: On [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937700/can-we-show-badge-number-on-android-app-icon-like-iphone) (which is a dupe of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905542/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-badge-to-an-application-icon-in-android)) I'm getting "Too many kids..." on both **Chrome 24.0.1312.57** and **Safari 6.0.2 (7536.26.17)**, so this isn't limited to Chrome.  This question's been uncloseable for me for over an hour (including plenty of cache flushing, etc), but maybe it'll get better after more waiting.

Comment: @Doorknob I was expanding the comments to add that very sentiment - but you had already done so. =( (+1)

Comment: @balpha Reproduced again for me, with the same example as blahdiblah. I posted the JS console trace.