# JavaScript error when trying to close a question via the Moderator Queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

When I try to close a question via the Moderator queue, I get the progress dots, but the close dialog never opens.  When I inspect it through Chromium dev tools, I see the following in the JavaScript console when I click the "Close question" button:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null stub.js:21 
$.fn.extend.center stub.js:21 
$.ajax.success full.js:150 
n jquery.min.js:2 
o.fireWith jquery.min.js:2 
w jquery.min.js:4 
d jquery.min.js:4
```

Comment: I'd suggest http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165828/cannot-vote-to-close-as-duplicate-in-chrome as a duplicate, but it isn't working...

Comment: @Gilles it's not a duplicate

Comment: I can't close anymore either,  Firefox 18.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recent JavaScript change only considered the case of closing directly from the post, not from the mod queue. The fix will be rolled out in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks for getting to it so quickly.

Comment: The mod queue working properly is fairly important :)